# CSS: center parent ul tag, left align li tag

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am setting a height on the ul tag and then rendering it as separate columns. I want this ul tag to be centered in the container div. And all the li tags to be left aligned. So far I have this:

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}

<div class= "container">
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 22</li>
    <li>item 333</li>
    <li>item 4444</li>
    <li>item 55555</li>
    <li>item 666666</li>
    <li>item 7777777</li>
    <li>item 88888888</li>
    <li>item 999999999</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: align-items targets the cross axis which is the x-axis in `flex-direction: column`. To vertical center the `ul` you must apply the flexbox to the container and target the Y-axis. also, the container must be higher than the content.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if that is what you had in mind, otherwise explain further please.

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I want the ul to be horizontally centered inside the div. and the li items will be left-aligned.

Comment: what do you mean by left aligned, all the way to the left of the container, so right at the left border?

Comment: inside the ul, all the li tags should start from the left, not the center.

Comment: they should all start from the left of each column.

Comment: thats how it is with the code I have sent you right now, unless you give ul a width you won't see it though.

Comment: how can I set the width to be responsive in this case? I don't wan't a fixed value. width: fit-content; messes it up

Comment: it already is responsive, if you add more li's they will take the space they need.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the div container into a flex-box, then use align-items to center the list.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class= "container">
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 22</li>
    <li>item 333</li>
    <li>item 4444</li>
    <li>item 55555</li>
    <li>item 666666</li>
    <li>item 7777777</li>
    <li>item 88888888</li>
    <li>item 999999999</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```